# jquery dropdown menus changing depending on previous menu values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I am the "tech guy" at the place I work, I have been tasked with creating a submission form for people to log technical issues with our products.

We need to have a system whereby we have say 4 drop down menus and the menus delve further down into the problem, at each level getting more and more specific.  All the menus would be visible to start with but only selectable once the previous menu was complete.

So the first menu may be:

-Menu 1-

*PC

*Printer

*Projector

Menu 2 would then allow options depending on which was selected.

So we may have the following, if "PC" was selected...

-Menu 2-

*Motherboard

*CPU

*Memory

And then assuming "Motherboard" the next menu would have

-Menu 3-

*Jumpers

*Cables

*Clean

I have little experience with JQuery, but I figure this is a good opportunity to learn.

I would really appreciate some help if at all possible.

Comment: Help with what? Do you have a specific question? Right now you've got a some cocktail napkin design and no code.

Comment: Ack!  your absolutely right.  I don't expect anything to be done for me.  I was just looking through the search results and wanted to get my thought process down in a question. I am off home now, but will get some code down later.

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite easy to do this with a MySQL database, and using different queries along the way.